# Transform Rows into Columns Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Is there a quick way to transfom a Table like this:

```
FIELD   |  VALUE
+-------+----------+
Address |  here
Name    |  Rainer
Tel     |  01234567
Other   |  idk
```

Into this:

```
Address | Name     | Tel     | Other
+-------+----------+---------+----------+
here    |  Rainer  | 01234567| idk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `pivot` method :

```
select * 
  from tab
 pivot(
       max(value) for field in ( 'Address' as "Address", 
                                 'Name'    as "Name", 
                                 'Tel'     as "Tel", 
                                 'Other'   as "Other" ) )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=060bc48dedfbabdfa282c6881be16e40)</kbd>

Comment: You don't need the nested sub-query. You can just do `SELECT * FROM tab PIVOT ...`

Comment: yes, thank you @MT0 .

Comment: you'rewelcome@DropMania

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    max(case when field = 'Address' then value end) Address,
    max(case when field = 'Name' then value end) Name
    max(case when field = 'Tel' then value end) Tel
    max(case when field = 'Other' then value end) Other
from mytable
```

In normal situation, you would need a column to `group by`, like for example a user id, so you can generate several records from the initial content.